# Do functions slow down performance

Tags: c#, performance, function

I am using c# to go through a loop and do something (this loop is massive, sometimes as big as 1,000,000 records long). I wanted to replace the inline code with code that does the exact same thing, except in a function.

I am guessing there is a slight decrease in performance, but will it actually be noticeable?

If I have a loop:

```
public void main()
{    
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       x += 1;
    }
}
```

Would my loop slow down if I did the same thing except this time making use of a function?

```
public void main()
{    
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       x = incrementInt(x);
    }
}

public int incrementInt(int x)
{
   return x + 1;
}
```

EDIT:

- Fixed logic bug, sorry for that.

Comment: Note that the second snippet is not equivalent to the first. In the second, `x` is never reassigned and will always be 0. There is a chance that the call to `incrementInt` will be elided completely.

Comment: There is only one way to find out. Try it out and if you can't measure a difference it doesn't matter.

Comment: Answer for your question in short is "YES".. The performace is hit due to big loops.

Comment: @captainsac unless the JIT can optimize it away. You can never be sure unless you measure.

Comment: ofcourse calling a method requires more work than running a simple increment expression. and you can simply try measuring to see if it's noticeable.

Comment: the function that you call for each loop, is it allowed execute all at the same time? if yes, you may try to search for async await in c#

Comment: Don't try to figure this out with simplified code. Measure the real thing.

Comment: One of these may be faster than the other. The only way to know for sure is to profile both approaches and compare the measurements. However, before you do all that work ask yourself, **is the slower one fast enough?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method call will always slow you down. But the JIT compiler can inline your method if a set of conditions is fullfilled which results in assembly code which is equivalent to your first example (if you fix the logic bug in your example).

The question you are indirectly asking is under which circumstances my method is inlined? There are many different rules but the easiest way to be sure that inlining does work is that you measure it. 
You can also use PerfView to find out for each method why it was not inlined. You can give the JIT compiler a hint to relax some of the rules and to inline a method with .NET 4.5

See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/01/20/aggressive-inlining-in-the-clr-45-jit/

There are some conditions described which prevent inlining:

- Methods marked with MethodImplOptions.NoInlining
- Methods larger than 32 bytes of IL
- Virtual methods
- Methods that take a large value type as a parameter
- Methods on MarshalByRef classes
- Methods with complicated flowgraphs
- Methods meeting other, more exotic criteria

If you follow the rules and measure carefully you can write highly performant code while keeping readable and maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a test application and run the performance analyzer on the code and the function call is slower than the loop (Although as mentioned above the two do different things.)

It is very simple to analyze these things in VS2012. Just click the "ANALYZE" menu item and select "Start Performance Analysis".

Comment: Did you do this with a release build or a debug build? It really should be a release build. Also, what is the difference, and (**this is actually the most important question**) _does the difference matter_?

Comment: Tested using the Release configuration. Also, the difference was roughly 5%. As for whether it matters to the person asking the question - I can't answer that since I don't know the context in which he is writing the code.

Comment: As an aside - if I fix the function so that it does the exact same thing as the for loop the difference is a lot larger. 83% of the processing for the function as opposed to 17% for the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this "ANALYZE", I am running with VS2010 web edition.

Comment: Thank you also for answering the question instead of complaining about how its not perfect and for releasing some stats. That's exactly whats I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function is slower than not calling it, but you can really ignore this.

Comment: What if the compiler in-lines the function? While there are many _it stands to reason_ answers in computer science, the standard response of _it stands to reason_ is very often wrong when it comes to performance and optimisation. The only way to know if there's a difference is to measure it.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier You are right. I wanted to emphasize that, decision shouldn't be based on this.

Comment: Binary Warrior is correct here. If you are worried about performance then the best way of determining bottle necks is to profile the code.